# Correct date format twiiter feed in app

Tags: android, listview, twitter, date-format, time-format

I have a twitter feed in setup in my app. 
But it the date isn't formatted right.

It now displays like this : Sat, 25 feb 2012 22:39:32 +0000 but I would like it to be in dutch and like this: 22:39u 25 februari 2012 (Dutch format and naming).

Or maybe if possible: "about 2 hours ago"

I used the code of this tutorial:
http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/

And I added:

```
((JSONObject)t).get("profile_image_url").toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for solution:

**Step-1** First we need to convert the twitter feed format to Date Obj. Like from twitter JSON response we are getting the created at value as:--

```
Sat Apr 02 17:14:28 +0000 2016
```

The corresponding format will be `"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"`
[Refer here for how to use formatting pattern letters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

So the code to cobert it to date object will be:

```
//Existing Format
    SimpleDateFormat createdDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");;
     Date dateObj = createdDateFormat.parse(date);
```

**Step-2** Convert this date Obj to your required format using new format pattern as below:

```
    //changing to new format
createdDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a");
 date = createdDateFormat.format(dateObj);
```

The final output is:-

```
Apr 03,2016 03:06 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say on that page, you need to use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Yeah, but I have no clue where and how, I tried it after the toString and before and... I really don't have a clue